# knockout edit is not working

Tags: knockout.js, edit

Following is the declaration and initialization of knockout objects

```
var EmployeeModel = function(data) {
    //Make the self as 'this' reference
    var self = this;

    //Declare observable which will be bind with UI 
    self.EmployeeID = ko.observable("");
    self.FirstName = ko.observable("");
    self.LastName = ko.observable("");

    var Employee = {
        EmployeeID: self.EmployeeID,
        FirstName: self.FirstName,
        LastName: self.LastName
    };


    self.Employees = ko.observableArray(data); // Contains the list of employees
    self.Employee = ko.observable();



    // Edit Employee details
    self.edit = function (Employee) {
        alert("edit");
        self.Employee(Employee);

        $("#EmployeePreview").css("display", "none");
        $("#PaneEdit").css("display", "block");
    }

    // Edit Employee details
    self.preview = function (Employee) {
        alert("preview");
        self.Employee(Employee);

        $("#PaneEdit").css("display", "none");
        $("#EmployeePreview").css("display", "block");
    }

    // Cancel Employee details
    self.cancel = function () {
        self.Employee(null);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Employee/GetData", null, function (data) {
        var viewModel = new EmployeeModel(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        viewModel.Employee(viewModel.Employees()[0]);
    });
});
```

Following is my HTML, which is working fine. On click of Edit, edit method of viewModel is also getting called

```
 <table cellspacing="10px" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="50%" style="vertical-align:text-top;" >
        <table  class="List" border="0" cellspacing="4px" cellpadding="4px">
        <!---->
         <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">

            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" width="5%"><img src="../../Images/photo.jpg" height="40px" width="40px" alt="Projects" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick=""/></td>
                <td width="5%">
                       <img data-bind="click: $root.preview" src="../../Images/Preview.png" height="16px" width="16px" alt="Projects" style="cursor:pointer;" "/>
                </td>
                <td data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="5%">
                     <img  data-bind="click: $root.edit" src="../../Images/Edit.png" height="16px" width="16px" alt="Projects" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="EditEmp();"/></td>
                <td data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
            </tr>
           <!---->
           </tbody>
           </table> 
        </td>
```

But the problem is following statement from edit method does not work even after trying many things

```
    self.Employee(Employee);
```

Can please anyone help me on this
Thanks in advance

Comment: <img  data-bind="click: $root.edit" src="../../Images/Edit.png" height="16px" width="16px" alt="Projects" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="EditEmp();"/>  remove onclick as you already have click binding and EditEmp is not defined.

Comment: $root.edit is getting called ... since alert is getting displayed. But following line is giving problem                        self.Employee(Employee);                                                             Even after removing EditEmp call it is not working

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 Employee variable one is simple object i.e var Employee
2 is observable and third is edit method parameter so don't get confused with parameter Employee it is just returning current data on which clicked.

```
var Employee = {   //this variable is useless
    EmployeeID: self.EmployeeID,
    FirstName: self.FirstName,
    LastName: self.LastName
};
```

hope it will work http://jsfiddle.net/CLCYC/1/

Comment: Thanks!! it worked.. but going ahead I am facing new problem                I am referring to following site                                         http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/add-edit-delete-data-using-knockout-in-mvc-4/                                                                It has following code to cancel the update                                        self.cancel = function () {
                self.Employee(null);
            }                                                                  Even after calling this method... my original object is changing